# Passing variable in pages through URL

Tags: php, variables, url

Here are two codes one works fine while other doesn't can anyone explain me what is wrong with second code.

```
$Id = $row['id'];
<a href="page2.php?Id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">Product></a>
```

The code above works fine. But the code below doesn't. On page two I am using get method.

```
<a href="page2.php?Id=$Id">Product></a>
```

Comment: <a href="page2.php?Id=<?php echo $Id ?>">Product></a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You not `print` `php` variable without `echo or php tag`

```
<a href="page2.php?Id=<?php echo $Id; ?>">Product></a>
```

So change this :-

```
href="page2.php?Id=$Id"
```

to this :-

```
href="page2.php?Id=<?php echo $Id; ?>"
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the reason your code was not working was a result of you closing the PHP tags, then attempting to use PHP code whilst your browser is only recognising HTML for that specific snippet of code. You always need to make sure you have the PHP tags opened when trying to call a PHP variable. As stated above you were also missing "echo", as follows:

```
<?php echo $Id; ?>
```

alternatively you could use:

```
<?= $Id; ?>
```

which is a little smaller and arguably more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this:

```
$Id = $_GET['Id'];
<a href="page2.php?Id=<?php echo $Id ?>">Product></a>
```

The one you are using like this:

```
<a href="page2.php?Id=$Id">Product></a>
```

is a plain HTML and it doesn't know that `$Id` is a php variable